# Keyboard layout visualization not working

Tags: 22.04, keyboard-layout

I'm creating a custom keyboard layout.
I've added it to the symbols and rules files and I can now select it from the keyboard layout widget. However, if I click "Show Keyboard Layout" nothing happens.
It could be something I did wrong in the symbols file, but I have no way to debug it.
Other layouts in the same country code are also not showing.

If I click "Show Keyboard Layout" for US English, or Dvorak it works fine.

Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The pictures of Keyboard Layout in the settings are like the food samples on the restaurant. They are not serious and they just look like it. When I select a PC105 US layout, it shows an ISO keyboard, doesn't matter the ANSI or TKL. When you swap the Control with CapsLock, neither does it.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka I find it useful for creating custom layouts. Also, it's the only way I know to validate the layout I've created.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can use xkbcomp to compile the symbols files. If something is not working, it will give you a line error.

```
xkbcomp /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/<code>
```

In my case I had some junk at the end of the file. After removing it, everything is now working fine.